# How can include the new columns to dataframe while replacing nan and avoid empty events

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, feature-extraction

I'm trying to extract 2 features out of `df['http_path']` and enrich the features. the problem is I used `?` sepaator. I waned to replace nan in case there was no value recorded in events/rows for further processing. Then I will replace `nan` for those events they don't have any info and iterate over the rows. To avoid repeated events, I want to keep those event the have info `A` ,`B` and `concat` to `df`. I tried following code:

```py
http_path = https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment
#http_path = ...A?B            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^

# new columns extracted from single column http_path
#api = A or /path/to/file
#param = B or param=42

http_path = df.http_path.str.split('?')   #The first ? seprator
api_param_df = pd.DataFrame([row if len(row) == 2 else row+[np.nan] for row in http_path.values], columns=["api", "param"])
df = pd.concat([df, api_param_df], axis=1)
```

Below is the example:

| http_path | API URL | URL parameters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment | path/to/file | param=42#fragment |
| https://example.org/path/to/file | path/to/file | NaN |

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` with regex `(?:https?://[^/]+/)?(?P<api>[^?]+)\??(?P<param>.+)?`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'http_path': ['https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment', 'https://example.org/path/to/file']})
df
#                                           http_path
#0  https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#frag...
#1                   https://example.org/path/to/file

df.http_path.str.extract('(?:https?://[^/]+/)?(?P<api>[^?]+)\??(?P<param>.+)?')

#            api              param
#0  path/to/file  param=42#fragment
#1  path/to/file                NaN
```

where in regex pattern:

- `(?:https?://[^/]+/)?` optionally matches domain but doesn't capture it
- `(?P<api>[^?]+)` matches everything up to `?`
- `\?` matches `?` literally
- `(?P<param>.+)` matches everything after `?`

Notice we also make `\?` and the second capture group optional so that when there are no query parameters in http path, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is it possible to update this solution for those cases/events with more than `?` (*Multi question marks* cases). So in these cases, we need to separate/extract **the first** `?` mark in the string to avoid the error. (e.g. A?B?C?D?E?...). In other words, to be standard, It should be sensitive to the first most left `?` mark.

Comment: I noticed `api` part didn't parse well in your solution. I already showed via `^` it means everything before `?` is not `api` but also some part of after domain. Maybe it was my bad to simplified via `A?B` which should be `....A?B`. I updated my question via a table.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove domain from the match.